"The total size of the x globals exported for future expression" in R-CMD-CHECK only on ubuntu-latest (devel)
Sorry, but I'm unsure if this is the right place to report my issue because it involves the confluence of three systems, only one of which is Ubuntu. I'm only coming here after first trying on help forums for the other two components (GitHub Actions and the R package future) have not been able to move forward. Please redirect me if there is a more appropriate forum.
I have an R-CMD-CHECK Github Actions workflow for my package at ale/.github/workflows/R-CMD-check.yaml at main · tripartio/ale. The action verifies my package against MacOS, Windows, and three versions of Ubuntu. Everything currently passes except for ubuntu-latest (devel), which fails on an issue related to the future parallel processing framework. Notably, the ubuntu-latest (release) and ubuntu-latest (oldrel-1) servers pass the test with no problem (as do MacOS and Windows); the problem is only with ubuntu-latest (devel).
Here is the relevant section from the most recent failed run: R-CMD-CHECK:
── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
* checking for file ‘.../DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘ale’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... ERROR
Error: --- re-building ‘ale-intro.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
--- finished re-building ‘ale-intro.Rmd’
--- re-building ‘ale-small-datasets.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
Quitting from lines 95-104 [lm_simple] (ale-small-datasets.Rmd)
Error: Error: processing vignette 'ale-small-datasets.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
The total size of the 56 globals exported for future expression ('function (it.x_cols); {; if (!silent && is.null(bins)) {; progress_iterator(); }; ale_results <- list_transpose(calc_ale(data, model, it.x_cols,; ...; it.rtn; })); }') is 1.85 GiB.. This exceeds the maximum allowed size of 500.00 MiB (option 'future.globals.maxSize'). The three largest globals are 'abort' (99.45 MiB of class 'function'), 'action_dots' (99.42 MiB of class 'function') and 'as_label' (99.42 MiB of class 'function')
--- failed re-building ‘ale-small-datasets.Rmd’
--- re-building ‘ale-statistics.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
--- finished re-building ‘ale-statistics.Rmd’
--- re-building ‘ale-x-datatypes.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
Quitting from lines 123-134 [cars_full] (ale-x-datatypes.Rmd)
Error: Error: processing vignette 'ale-x-datatypes.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
The total size of the 129 globals exported for future expression ('function (btit, btit.idxs); {; if (!silent) {; progress_iterator(); }; btit.model <- NULL; ...; else {; NULL; }') is 4.01 GiB.. This exceeds the maximum allowed size of 500.00 MiB (option 'future.globals.maxSize'). The three largest globals are 'abort' (83.31 MiB of class 'function'), 'abort_context' (83.30 MiB of class 'function') and 'trace_back' (83.29 MiB of class 'function')
--- failed re-building ‘ale-x-datatypes.Rmd’
SUMMARY: processing the following files failed:
  ‘ale-small-datasets.Rmd’ ‘ale-x-datatypes.Rmd’
Error: Error: Vignette re-building failed.
Execution halted
Error: Error in proc$get_built_file() : Build process failed
Calls: <Anonymous> ... build_package -> with_envvar -> force -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
Run ## --------------------------------------------------------------------
Show testthat output
Run actions/upload-artifact@v4
Warning: No files were found with the provided path: /home/runner/work/ale/ale/check. No artifacts will be uploaded.
Run actions/upload-artifact@v4
No files were found with the provided path: /home/runner/work/ale/ale/check/**/tests*/testthat/_snaps. No artifacts will be uploaded.

I tried a few things from my bug report at the GitHub Actions thread of the Posit Community, but the few pointers I received and tried did not help. Following the tips from my bug report in future package GitHub issues, I can confirm that the problem is not with a misconfiguration of the future package itself but is strictly isolated to the ubuntu-latest (devel) server invoked by the GitHub action.
The numbers of exported objects specified in the log above are not unusual, but what I find very odd is the massive size of the first three listed functions:

"The three largest globals are 'abort' (99.45 MiB of class 'function'), 'action_dots' (99.42 MiB of class 'function') and 'as_label' (99.41 MiB of class 'function')"
"The three largest globals are 'abort' (83.31 MiB of class 'function'), 'abort_context' (83.30 MiB of class 'function') and 'trace_back' (83.29 MiB of class 'function')".

As far as I can tell, these are all rlang functions; I have no idea why they would be so big. As far as I can tell from the build log above, it seems that the ubuntu-latest (devel) server perceives that the {future} parallelization package does not allocate enough space for the objects in my package test. None of the other builds (including the other two Ubuntu builds) report this error.
It seems to me that for some reason the {future} installation on ubuntu-latest (devel) is grossly overestimating the storage needs for the package, which is not a problem on earlier versions of Ubuntu. Perhaps there's a memory leak somewhere? If ubuntu-latest (devel) represents an upcoming release of Ubuntu, then this issue should probably be investigated and resolved now before it makes it to a release version of Ubuntu.
I know this is a very specific issue about a specific system, but if  someone could at least direct me to who maintains the R-CMD-CHECK GitHub Action, that would be a great pointer. As I mentioned at the beginning, I posted on their forum first of all but have not been able to receive the necessary help there.

You missed the most appropriate place to report this: Report this as an open issue in Github itself..  Use Label bug and help wanted as a start

@eyoung100 Could you please repost your comment as an answer with an explanation of why that is "the most appropriate place to report this"? If your answer is the best,  you'll get the bounty on this question.

My Answer has been posted.

Where Computer Bugs Go To Die
I'll be the first to admit, I started programming when VB6 was converted to .NET where you could take any language supported by that company everyone either loves or hates, and send a program through an intermediary compiler and end up with the same machine language code regardless.  Things were a lot different then, as Microsoft's approach to handling bugs then was top-down and a bit clunky.  That "dealing with clunky top down mess" is what led me to the Linux Ecosystem in the first place.  Part of that ecosystem is the bug reporting system.  Some examples:

Debian's Bug Reporting Page
Ubuntu's Bug Tracker
Arch's New GitLab Tracker

Linux users may argue for eons about which distribution they like or what best suits their needs but as the above links illustrate every distribution firmly believes in the bottom up approach to fixing items. This approach was again strengthened when the Linux Kernel was moved from CVS to Github.
How Does This Apply to the OP's Question?
The bottom up approach to software management has now become mainstream as programmers and non-programmers alike are free to both browse source code and report bugs, now called issues, via GitHub as a whole. While I don't use R, although I plan to read this book, after stumbling onto this question, the actions the OP is having trouble with have their own Github Repository which the OP correctly found.  Since development of these actions no longer belong to one contributor as seen on the contributor's page, the OP's issue should be reported on the corresponding issue page.  Posting it there will allow the 88 current contributors, some of who have a very precise understanding of the way the actions were built, can comment and communicate with the OP directly. This direct communication is needed because:

The OP has all the relevant logs, build steps etc. that can be posted in the issue tracker instead of linking them all together on separate forums.
The contributors who read the issue can provide the proper direction to point the OP as to whether this is an R Actions issue or an issue with Ubuntu (current).
If more information is needed the commenters will know exactly what to ask for.


+1 Thanks for the redirection. I'll wait until the bounty expires before I post this issue to https://github.com/r-lib/actions/issues because 1) I'd like to see if I get a more direct response to my inquiry; and 2) I don't want to cross-post while this question (or its bounty, at least) is still active. With the three places I've posted this question so far (Ask Ubuntu being the 3rd), I've always avoided simultaneous cross-posting.

On a side note, if you're already a computer programmer, then https://r4ds.hadley.nz/intro (by the same author) is probably a better starting point than https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/, which is for non-programmers.

@Tripartio Both look promising.  I still need to "investigate" if Jetbrainz has an R IDE or if I should try R Studio

This is the first time I've heard of Jetbrains, but apparently, they do (via an extension): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/r-plugin-support.html
